# TypeCast To Overcome Interface Limitation?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm using IDbCommand and IDbDataParameter interfaces for my SQL db logic but realized that I can't get `sqlCommand.parameter["ID"]`.Value because of an interface restriction.

Is it good practice to type cast an interfaced object to overcome a limitation of an interface?

Example

```
using (IDbCommand SqlCmd = CommandProvider.GetSPCommand(conn))
{
    // setup sqlcmd with output paramter and executenonquery ...
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(((SqlCommand)SqlCmd).Parameters["ID"].Value);
 }
```

Comment: Generally, if you need to do something that the interface doesn't expose then you're using the wrong interface.  What is the type returned by `GetSPCommand()`?

Comment: The returned type is SqlCommand

Comment: In that case you're not gaining anything by using the interface in the first place.  Just use `SqlCommand` as the variable type.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think that's what I will do then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not good practice.

First, you shouldn't downcast unless *absolutely* necessary. If you need a value that is only provided by a interface implementation, start with that implementation. In your case, if `CommandProvider.GetSPCommand` returns a SqlCommand, then just do:

```
using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = CommandProvider.GetSPCommand(conn))
{
    // setup sqlcmd with output paramter and executenonquery ...
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(((SqlCommand)SqlCmd).Parameters["ID"].Value);
 }
```

If it *doesn't* do that, then you've run into the second thing you have wrong which is doing a cast before checking if it is safe. If the returned item *wasn't* a `SqlCommand` your code would throw an `InvalidCastException`. Instead, check with the `as` operator:

```
using (IDbCommand SqlCmd = CommandProvider.GetSPCommand(conn))
{
    SqlCommand fullSqlCommand = SqlCmd as SqlCommand;
    if (fullSqlCommand != null)
    {
       // setup sqlcmd with output paramter and executenonquery ...
       ID = Convert.ToInt32(fullSqlCommand.Parameters["ID"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        //Some failsafe
    }
 }
```

Of course, only using the interface is the preferred option, but that can be difficult when, as in this case, you don't control it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  That helps clarify my issue, I suppose I should declare with SqlCommand rather than the IDbCommand interface.

Answer (score 0):

Bradley is correct and concise with his answer.  I would also add that based on your code, accessing stored procedure parameters doesn't necessarily have to be factor that couples you to a specific implementation.  One of my favorite tools to achieve *database independent* data access code is the wonderful magic of **Dapper**.  Believe it or not, it's the data access library that runs Stack Overflow!

From their [documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), you can add and access parameters with this code:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); 

int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

You could then keep coding against abstractions like IDbCommand, IDbConnection, etc.  Dapper has a highly performant way of taking values from a database and easily converting them to C# types (which could potentially eliminate your need to type cast in a few areas).

Casting via hard-cast (using [parentheses](http://richardrflores.com/2015/03/18/coercion-of-types-soft-casting.html)) or soft-casting, at least in my book, are both considered code smell (though I agree with Bradley - go soft if you must).  Only in a few specific areas would one have an absolute need to do it.  For a trivial app, feel free to take a full dependency on your database and be along your merry way.  For any non-trivial enterprise app, taking a hard dependency on your database will eventually vendor-lock your application stack and put future refactoring at risk.